# Siebel compile integration with Jenkins CI

Tags: jenkins, siebel

I have a task to configure Siebel compile with Jenkins CI tool. I dont know much about siebel. So, please suggest if anyone have ever configure these two before or anyone have some knowledge about integration or tools.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Integrating Siebel build with Jenkins is pretty simple. Steps are as follow,

1. Add new jnlp slave(window machine) where you have install you toold.
2. Use repository tool to download object on you window machine. For SVN you can use silk svn or if you are using git them that can be directly integrated with your job as Jenkins provide plugin for same.
3. Define your folder structure with main folder. like for applet,bc,bo etc.
4. Call you `siebdev.exe` to import all object. You can do it by the option `/batchimport`. It will import all sif file present in directory

`siebdev.exe " /c "D:\sea81\Tools_2\BIN\ENU\tools.cfg" /d "Local" /u "USER" /p "PASSWORD!" /batchimport "Siebel Repository" overwrite "d:\workspace_future\objects/Applet"`

5. Once import is complete,start compiling.

`tools.cfg" /d "Local" /u "USER" /p "PASSWORD!" /bc "Siebel Repository" "d:\workspace_future\built\siebel.srf"`

6. Now you can also create Browser script, zip it and upload on any ftp system, which can be used to download files during integration.

There is many things which you can play with. For example I create a unique build file which contains repository with latest change, srf file, browser script,and other reference data like lov,system preference etc.

Comment: can you please share the scripts if possible? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

http://siebelunleashed.com/how-to-automate-siebel-full-compile/

It shows how to automate a siebel compilation. Use the first part (command line stuff) and put that in the "Execute Windows Batch Command" section of Jenkins.

I'm not sure how much experience you have with Jenkins, so if you need more details, please post a comment.